# Xamarin forms xaml Listview not updating as per collection changes

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Hi I am trying to update `listView` by adding and removing item from it. Adding Item in `listview` works fine in iOS and android well. But removing any item from it gives wrong out on android, it works perfect on iOS.
In Android : whenever I delete a item from listview it deletes from collection but on UI it deletes last item present on UI after deleting when I add once again it adds previously deleted item into list not new new fresh item. Please check code I used

```
<ListView  RowHeight="100" HorizontalOptions="End" ItemsSource="{Binding GuidePrices, Mode=OneWay}" >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <ViewCell.View>
          <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal">
            <controls:BindablePicker ItemsSource="{Binding Prices}" WidthRequest="150" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Button Text="Add" IsVisible="{Binding Action}">
              <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:BehaviorCollection>
                  <b:EventToCommand  CommandNameContext="{b:RelativeContext CampsiteViewPage}"
                        EventName="Clicked" 
                        CommandName="AddPriceListCommand"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" /> 
                </b:BehaviorCollection>
              </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Button>
             <Button Text="Delete" IsVisible="{Binding Action, Converter={StaticResource cnvInvert}}">
              <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:BehaviorCollection>
                  <b:EventToCommand  CommandNameContext="{b:RelativeContext CampsiteViewPage}"
                        EventName="Clicked" 
                        CommandName="DeletePriceListCommand"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}" /> 
                </b:BehaviorCollection>
              </b:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Button>
          </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell.View>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

--ViewModel code for on add and delete command

```
this.AddPriceListCommand = new Command((s) =>
        {
            if (_guidePrices != null)
                {
                _guidePrices.Add(new PricesListModel() { ListId = Guid.NewGuid(), Action = false, Prices = _campsite.Guides[0].Prices });
                }
        });

        this.DeletePriceListCommand = new Command((sender) => {

        var  _priseList = (from priceList in _guidePrices
                           where priceList == (PricesListModel)sender
                   select priceList).ToList();
        _guidePrices.RemoveAt(_guidePrices.IndexOf((PricesListModel)sender));

            });
```

I am not able find cause why this behave on android as same code works in ios as expected.

Comment: What Xamarin.Forms version are you using?

Comment: here is my VS configuration of xamarin                                                                              
Xamarin   3.9.519.0 (5667ef4)
Xamarin.Android   4.20.0.37 
Xamarin.iOS   8.8.1.0 
Xamarin.iOS Unified Migration   1.0

Answer (score -1):

What is the type of `_guidePrices`? Removing an item from a `List<T>` does not update the UI. You need to use the `ObservableCollction<T>` or raise PropertyChanged event notify UI to update

Comment: Yes I am using 'ObservableCollction<T> ' , also my listview get updated BUT whenever I delete middle item in list it delete last item from UI. Also when I I add new item instead of adding fresh item it adds deleted item at the end. Deleting ok in observable collection. IT WORKS IN iOS AS EXPECTED. Not getting why with android tablet.

Comment: Prashant any guess for this behavior in android so I can work around.

Comment: I have no idea, I will have to try it out on my machine